# Thread Options Facebook Comments Plugin Not Working On Chrome

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, comments

How to make Facebook Comments plugin work on Google Chrome? It shows up in IE9 and Opera, but for some reason isn't accessible on Google Chrome.

Thanks in advance!

Codes Used(From Facebook Developers Comments):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://websiteurl....." data-num-posts="1" data-width="500"></div>
```

Comment: I'd like an answer for this too. I'm using the Facebook Comments wordpress plugin, and it it too is displaying everywhere but Chrome.

(Posted this comment as an answer accidentally. Whoops.)

Comment: Since my comments plugin works in Chrome on a normal page, it's kinda hard to troubleshoot without a URL that is not working in Chrome.

Comment: Again, without a working URL to look at, it's going to be hard to troubleshoot since I cannot reproduce this issue at all in Chrome on some test pages.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the facebook xmlns attribute in the html header? I had some problems in a webpage with this plugin untill I added it.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Besides, I use attributes in comments' div without the "data" and it works in all browsers:

```
<fb:comments href="WEB_URL" num_posts="10" width="500" notify="true"></fb:comments>
```

Comment: I realize now that this is the XFBML version in [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) I have no problem with this version in Chrome, perhaps the problem is 'data-' attributes?

Comment: I'll try these suggestions out. It also might have something to do with the million fb-root divs courtesy of various WP plugins.

Comment: Mmm, it could be, but fb-root div is identified by an 'id', not a class, so only one of them should be selected and used by all plugins...

Comment: Not sure that's true. ID is unique by HTML spec, I believe that any behavior manipulating objects in the DOM by ID when there are duplicate IDs is undefines.